# if a value in one column does not exist fill in with another value in r

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, fill

In the following df, the `d` from column A might not always be present

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
  B = c("0,1","0,2","0,12","0,11"))
```

I want to create a new column "C" which will be filled with the value from column "B" corresponding to "d" from column "A", if `d` exists, to get this result

```
> df
  A    B    C
  a  0,1 0,11
  b  0,2 0,11
  c 0,12 0,11
  d 0,11 0,11
```

But in case `d` does not exist in column "A", I would like to get the value for "c" to be filled in column "C"

```
row.names(df) <- df$A
df <- df %>% mutate(C = case_when(A == "d" ~ paste(df["d", "B"]), A == "c" ~ paste(df["c", "B"]))) %>% fill(C, .direction = "downup")

> df
  A    B    C
  a  0,1 0,12
  b  0,2 0,12
  c 0,12 0,12
```

But if `d` exists I get this result, which is not what I want, as the value for `c` is kept in column C

```
> df
  A    B    C
a a  0,1 <NA>
b b  0,2 <NA>
c c 0,12 0,12
d d 0,11 0,11
```

Comment: if "d" existis, then the output should be this                                                                    
  `> df
  A    B    C
  a  0,1 0,11
  b  0,2 0,11
  c 0,12 0,11
  d 0,11 0,11`

Comment: if "d" exists, the value for d should be filled in all the rows in column "C", and the "c" should be ignored.

Comment: I am sorry that it is confusing but this is actually the second sentence in my post.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(C = coalesce(B[which(A == 'd')[1]], B[which(A == 'c')[1]]))
```

-output

```
 A    B    C
1 a  0,1 0,11
2 b  0,2 0,11
3 c 0,12 0,11
4 d 0,11 0,11
```

or after removing the 'd' row

```
df %>%
    slice(-4) %>%
    mutate(C = coalesce(B[which(A == 'd')[1]], B[which(A == 'c')[1]]))
  A    B    C
1 a  0,1 0,12
2 b  0,2 0,12
3 c 0,12 0,12
```

---

Or another option is to convert to `factor` with `levels` specified in the order

```
library(forcats)
f1 <- function(dat, lvls) {
       dat %>%
           mutate(tmp = fct_relevel(A, lvls),
                  C = B[match(first(levels(droplevels(tmp))), A)],
                  tmp = NULL)
}
```

and call as

```
> f1(df, lvls = c('d', 'c'))
  A    B    C
1 a  0,1 0,11
2 b  0,2 0,11
3 c 0,12 0,11
4 d 0,11 0,11
> f1(df[-4, ], lvls = c('d', 'c'))
  A    B    C
1 a  0,1 0,12
2 b  0,2 0,12
3 c 0,12 0,12
```

Comment: thanks, did work to fill, but as I wrote when d is available it gives this > ´´´ df
  A    B    C
a a  0,1 <NA>
b b  0,2 <NA>
c c 0,12 0,12
d d 0,11 0,11 ´´´  instead I need only the d value and not the c

Comment: @jkinstack so you meant when `d` id available, don't fill, and else fill?

Comment: when d is available I want only the d value (0.11) to be filled in column C, when d is not available I want the c value to be filled in the C column (0.12)

Comment: I will use your comment to update the question, it might easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution.

```
if(any(df$A == "c")) df$C <- df$B[df$A == "c"]
if(any(df$A == "d")) df$C[df$A == "d"] <- df$B[df$A == "d"]

df
#  A    B    C
#1 a  0,1 0,12
#2 b  0,2 0,12
#3 c 0,12 0,12
#4 d 0,11 0,11
```

---

Another, one-liner, `ifelse` solution.

```
df$C <- ifelse(df$A == "d", df$B, df$B[df$A == "c"][1])
```

Comment: thanks, but if d exists, I need the `df$C[df$A == "d"] <- df$B[df$A == "d"]` to be filled in the "C", when d does not exist, I need the `df$C[df$A == "c"] <- df$B[df$A == "c"]`

Comment: I see now it works, but is there a way to have it in a loop or smt so that it works always no matter if d is there?

Comment: @jkinstack The code now works even if there is no `"d"`, it fails only if there is no `"c"`, in which case `any(df$A == "c")` returns FALSE and the column `C` is not created. As for `"d"`, when the condition `if(any(df$A == "d"))` returns FALSE the new column *assumed to exist because `"c"` is assumed to always exist* does not change.

Comment: yes, I understand, but I was thinking if there is a way to adjust it so that it can run without someone having to check if d is there or the "FALSE" in the result. So I was thinking if there is a way to say in one line, if  `d` is not there then use `c`

Comment: @jkinstack See the edit. Note that I still prefer my answer above, `ifelse` is slower than indexed assignment.